# What software can help auto construct software skeleton from various OO design charts?

Tags: open-source, software-development

I once used the [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/). It seems it can help me auto generate the software system skeleton based on the OO design expressed in EA. But its UI is kind of not easy to use. Some one even said its UI is actaully *Unique Interface*.

So, I am wondering if there's any similar alternatives. I hope I can express my OO architecture design in class/inteface diagram, flow chart, sequence chart, etc. And then this tool can help me generate a software skeleton.

It would be better if it's a freeware.